# how to get upgrade button to work when upgrading nuget package in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package

In VS 2019, I want to upgrade System.Text.Encodings.Web from 4.6.0

But the 'install' button  is greyed out. Any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...` and go to the [`Updates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#update-a-package) tab. You will be able to update `System.Text.Encodings.Web` or any other installed package there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - that answered my question !